# Create Restful API to read mysql query as a query string

Tags: mysql, web-services

My client asked me to develop a authenticated restful PHP Api which will read mysql query as a request and sends result set as a json response. But this api should allow to read only select queries.If any query with update/drop/truncate etc .. then it should through some error message like no permission etc.. But is it possible to read mysql queries as a query string ? Any help / suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which programming language will your application code (API backend) code will be in ?

Comment: Hi, it should be In PHP

Comment: Don't do this unless you are in a completely trusted environment. Even if you only allow `SELECT` queries, people can still exploit this in a large number of ways.